# Need better font control

Tags: fonts

Generally many programs have a menu item to raise/lower current font size.  This is much more convenient than trying to root around in in internal mathematica options.

I need to change ALL default fonts not just particular ones.  For instance the help system font is itself too small on my laptop.  I hope there is a way to do what I want without having to know about a lot of different settings.  I am not interested in how uber flexible internal settings are but in having a product that is comfortably readable and useable without a lot of fooling around.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the magnification (Window -> Magnification)?

Comment: @rm-rf There were couple of posts here that working on magnification different than 100% causes errors. I've faced it too.

Comment: User, I hope that you will find at least one answer to one of the three questions now linked in the "already has an answer" header to satisfy.  If you do not please let me know in what way they all fail you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For various reasons, mostly connected to poor eyesight, I frequently want to change window size and magnification. To make this convenient, I have built a palette that has buttons to set these frequently used options. It might help you too. Here is the code ...

```
With[{setMag = (CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], Magnification] = #) &},
  CreatePalette[
    Framed@Column[{
      Style[" Magnification", Bold, 11],
      Button["100%", setMag[1.], Appearance -> "Palette", ImageSize -> 120],
      Button["125%", setMag[1.25], Appearance -> "Palette"],
      Button["150%", setMag[1.5], Appearance -> "Palette"],
      Style[" Ruler", Bold, 11],
      Button["Show",
        With[{wtb = CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowToolbars]}, 
          CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowToolbars] = 
            DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[{wtb, "RulerBar"}]],
        Appearance -> "Palette"],
      Button["Hide",
        With[{wtb = CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowToolbars]},
        Switch[wtb,
         "RulerBar", CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowToolbars] = {},
         _List, CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowToolbars] = 
           DeleteCases[wtb, "RulerBar"]]],
        Appearance -> "Palette"],
      Style[" Size", Bold, 11],
      Button["880 \[Times] 1000", 
        CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowSize] = {880, 1000}, 
        Appearance -> "Palette"],
      Button["725 \[Times] 755", 
        CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], WindowSize] = {725, 755}, 
        Appearance -> "Palette"]}],
    WindowTitle -> "Window Options"]];
```

... and here is how it looks when deployed.

[image: palette.png]

To install the palette, evaluate the code, select Install Palettes... from the Palettes menu, and complete the ensuing dialog box. After installation the new palette will appear in the Palettes menu.

Note: You will probably get an alert asking to save the palette as a notebook, even **after** installation. Just ignore it -- the installation process saves the palette to the correct directory.