# Is it possible to auto-load documentation for current function?

Tags: notebooks, documentation

As much as *Mathematica* amazes me with endless variety of integrated functions and packages, inconsistency with functions parameters or finding details about a function takes some time and isn't as awesome.

Would it be possible to autoload documentation for currently typed function name? You can see attached screenshot to get the better idea of what I mean.

I know about `Ctrl + Shift + K`, but I'm interested in something more comprehensive.

[image]Thanks!

Comment: Place your mouse cursor anywhere in the symbol or at its end and press the F1 key.

Comment: I know about F1 but resizing window, clicking on "Details" takes a lot of time if you repeat it many times. Help also  takes some time to load

Comment: You have to resize only once. The second time you use F1 it uses the previous size.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35370/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-details-section-of-the-documentation-expand-by-defa

Comment: For making resizing easy and other common window option setting, you might [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31939/3066) useful.

Comment: The new mathematica 12 does not have that yellow field color scheme, where it says 'example data' in the image above. Is there anyway to make mathematica go back to this classic look.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the following code will be easy to put in shortkeys file but it is a good start:

```
curr = EvaluationNotebook[];
nb = Documentation`HelpLookup["Plot"];
SelectionMove[Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "NotesSection"][[1]], All, Cell];
FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "OpenCloseGroup"];
FrontEndTokenExecute[#, "WindowMiniaturize"] & /@ DeleteCases[Notebooks[], nb | curr];
FrontEndTokenExecute["TileWindowsTall"]
```

What procedures above do:

- line(2):  open documentation [reference link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16483/5478)
- line(3-4):open `Details & Options` section
- line(5):  minimize all the windows except out current notebook and help.
- line(6):  tile windows tall :P

Results at the bottom of the post.

[reference link to `FrontEndTokens`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2572/5478)

---

#### A different Idea:

Instead of creating a new shortcut for this operation it probably can be done as follows:

[Capture F1 with that code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41910/5478) but use the code from above. There will be an issue with detecting which notebooks should be minimized but I think this way is promissing. I don't have time to try it now, maybe later, but I can't promise.

---

#### Before:

> [image]

#### After:

> [image]